# How to call a function in JS without calling the function of Parent element

Tags: javascript, function, dom-events, parent-child

How can I make the button disappear work in the example below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1" style="height: 100px; background-color: red;" onclick="parent()">
        <button onclick="child()">disapear</button>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        function parent(elem) {
            document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "block";
        }
        function child(elem) {
            document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on button disappear I want to call only its function - which is `child()`. not the `parent()` function which is when I click the div

Comment: This is a case of Event getting bubbled I have made a small example based on your question https://jsfiddle.net/Le8nkoqf/ please check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/bubbles for bubbling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1" style="height: 100px; background-color: red;" onclick="parent(event)">
        <button onclick="child(event)">disapear</button>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        function parent(elem) {
            document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "block";
        }
        function child(elem) {
            elem.stopPropagation();
            document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```